# How do I increase my office internet speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, android

Can you please suggest what should I do to increase my internet speed per PC?

My details:
I have 6 Macs and 10 PC/Laptops in my office. We have a 12 MBPS internet plan. We have a Wireless router through which we connect to the LAN. Although there are 16 devices, the DHCP Client list of the router shows more than 25 devices. That is because we run Android emulators as well and also iPhone, iPad, etc.

In this setup, can you please suggest what should we do to increase Office internet speed?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: unless your a room full of geeks, 12mbs should do 25+ people fine. I would suggest upgrading your router to a microtik board. It will do better with the amount of devices you have connected.

Comment: What is a microtik board? And which routers have it?

Comment: you can see what mikrotik is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikroTik
you can see some of their products here:
http://www.mikrotik.com/
for you ide reccomend this board:
http://routerboard.com/RB2011UAS-2HnD-IN

Comment: Apart from replacing the router, is there anything I can do in my network setup?

Comment: You want to increase the speed, but what problems do you run into? Are the employees all need the same internet speed? Are there some that need more speed for for example downloading files from ftp servers etc? You could cap the speed for certain ip/mac addresses. By managing the traffic you could make sure the people that need the speed the most have it when requested.

Comment: What speeds are you getting out? Are internal speeds OK? We need more information. Also, what type of plan? DSL? Cable? Business line?

Comment: We are using Broadband connection (Cable). Internal speed is also slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QOS (quality of service)  You can prioritize your internet so the right people and/or websites will be given priority over other users.

a Caching server.
It stores downloaded files so when another PC access the same file it just retrieves it locally instead of downloading again.  Take for instance Windows Updates, MAC OS updates, and android updates.  Also if 10 people visit the same website the 1st user downloads it and the other 9 get it from the local caching server.

Do multiple users download the same files? If yes, maybe a file server to store common files so 1 user downloads it and everyone has access.

I would have to know more about the kinds and types of things downloaded to help further.
How much is website viewing?  How much is streaming content?  What types of services are used http,ftp,ssh, or etc?

If you physically have 12mb/s that is all you have, but the above techniques will help you use it more efficiently and have more effective bandwidth.

Comment: How can setup a caching server? Are there any good software available for that?

Comment: Yes.  http://www.squid-cache.org/   Take spare computer load some kind of linux on it, and then install the above package, or if the distro includes it use the included one.  Set the computer with a static IP.  Finally set up proxy on all your computers and give it the new proxy/caching server ip address.   See also   http://www.visolve.com/squid/sqguide.php     The more hard drive available the more will be cached the less you download.

Comment: If you main router is not gigabit you should consider upgrading it because 100mbit= approx max 12mb/s and gigabit = approx max of 125mb/s.  Also if the caching server PC does not have gigabit get it a gigabit NIC for the same reason.

Comment: I used Squid on windows 7 and here are the links that I found useful:

Comment: http://www.pimp-my-rig.com/2011/06/squid-caching-proxy-server-windows.html

Comment: http://www.talk.web.id/2009/08/installing-squid-web-proxy-server-on-windows-7/